# Spring 3 MVC, Tomcat Web App hangs after a few requests

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc

I created (my first) small spring 3 MVC application, but ran into an issue which is a little bit mysterious for me.

The application has a few forms to manipulate a database. I created one Controller Java class which maps all requests to java Methods (see code). 
After a few requests in the browser the web app crashes. The code for manipulating a database entry is called successfully but the reload of the page seem to fail.

Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("/usermanager")
public String getUserInfo(Map<String, Object> map) throws ServletException {
    try {
        map.put("userInfo", userService.getUserInfo());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
    return "usermanager";
}

@RequestMapping("/updateUserInfo")
public String updateUserInfo(@ModelAttribute("userInfo") User user) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    userService.storeUserInfo(user);
    return "redirect:/service/usermanager";
}
```

The structure is really easy, the request usermanager is called to show the table data. The site shows a form where I can edit my data, submitting the form calls the updateUserInfo request.
After a few times the request hangs at return "usermanager";.

Did someone have an explanation for this behavior, Or an idea?

---

Edit:
BTW: There are no Exceptions or something else. The web app simply hangs.

Many thanks,
Regards Sascha

Comment: Have you tried to attach a debugger or run your tomcat in VisualVM to see, where the application hangs?

Comment: Can you please post the code of `userService.getUserInfo()`?

Comment: ... in what environment does this happen? What are you using to for development? What are you using to interact with the db: Hibernate, pure jdbc, etc?

Comment: please post the code of userService.getUserInfo() I think there is some connection leak

Answer (score 2):

i found the bug. Looked at the wrong place.

The error occurs indeed in the getUserInfo(). But it is a more general problem with my database connection method.

Everytime a do a database query, i called: `connection = dataSource.getConnection();`
That causes the leak. 
It is better to check if there is already a connection :-D

```
if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

BTW I use an embedded Derby Database which is accessed by the jdbcTemplate.

Sometimes we do not see the wood for the trees :-)

Thanks for your effort.
Have a nice day
Sascha

Comment: thanks for the info on the connection method. this resolved my issue with tomcat hanging...